# need to count number of occurrences of given strings in an if statement

Tags: python, if-statement

so in my function one of my if statements is that the string does not have more than 1 occurrence of a string that is in a list.

for example:

```
list = ['a','b']
```

i need to check if a string has more than one of those 2 characters in it or else it will move on to the next if statement.

```
s = 'aloha'
```

s will pass the if statement because b is not in s.

```
s = 'abcd'
```

s should fail this if statement because both a and b are in s.

more examples if it's not clear enough.

```
s = 'aaab'
```

this will fail the if statement and move on.

```
s = 'aaloh'
```

this will also fail

my if statement was:

```
if s.count('a') == 1 or s.count('b') == 1:
```

This if statement doesn't work

my question is, is there a way to check this without doing a for loop before hand?

Comment: please post your complete code so we can see exactly what you're doing

Answer (score 2):

You'll need a for loop, but you can still do it one line.

```py
if sum(char in s for char in list) > 1:
```

If you wanted to look for specific numbers of a given character with some threshold, put your list of characters into a `dict` like `d = {'a': 1, 'b': 4}`.

```py
if sum(s.count(char) >= count for char, count in d.items) > THRESHOLD:
```

## Update

The OP commented that he wants a

> a function that does something with the string if and only if that string doesn't have both 'a' and 'b' in the string. It can only have one of the two and not both and also only one occurrence of it.

Because OP's original post wanted to generalize 'a' and 'b' to a sequence of characters `list`, I interpret his meaning to be he wants an expression that returns `True` for a string `s` if and only if `s` has exactly one occurrence of exactly one element of a list of characters `list`.

```py
sum(s.count(char) for char in list) <= 1
```

In OP's simple example, `list = ['a', 'b']`.

Comment: Almost there; use `s.count(char)` instead. As soon as more than one character is present more than once, *or* two characters are present just once, the sum will go over 2.

Comment: Frankly, I'm not entirely clear what the OP is after. For example, I'm not sure what you mean by "present". Are you referring to a character's presence in OP's `list`, or in OP's `s`?

Comment: Yeah, rereading the question again, it's not clear to me either.

Comment: basically i'm making a function that does something with the string if and only if that string doesn't have both 'a' and 'b' in the string. It can only have one of the two and not both and also only one occurrence of it.